# Help needed in selecting the power architecture for my project

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, architecture

I had some trouble in finalizing the power architecture for my upcoming project.

In a brief summary about the project, I am using a GPS device to acquire location of the vehicle and control two solenoid valves to spray  chemicals according to the location co-ordinates. The device will be turned on/off via a key switch.
Regarding the valves, they will be operated in a complementary manner. Like valve A will be in default on state and valve B will be default off. When valve B will be on, valve A will be off and vice-versa.

There is an additional third relay in the design but that is just as a future provision.

The confusion in architecture revolves around the relay circuits deployed to control these valves. There are two options, either to go ahead with a 5V relay or a 3V relay (coil voltage.)

The overall two architectures I need help in selection with are as below:

[image]

[image]

In power architecture 2, there is a separate 5V buck that powers the 5V relay's coil and the rest of control circuit is powered via a 3.3V buck.

In power architecture 3, there is a single 3.3V buck that feeds the control circuit along with the 3V relay coils.

Since the vehicle will be moving when the valves will be controlled on/off, the relays will be turned on/off at 5-10 Hz switching frequency.

Option 3 is the cheapest option.
I am worried that if I consider the power architecture 3, there may be issues like the coil switching may create some noise that will affect the supply line and eventually the controllers performance.

Wanted to know about all measures that can be taken to ensure sufficient isolation between the two parts of voltages coming out from the same source.
Though the relays definitely have free wheeling diodes across the coils I am still concerned that there may be some issues, which I wish to understand via the forum here.

The design's PCB will be a four layer board. The overall communication interfaces on the board at their respective speed is as follows:

[image]

Two possible ways I could think of are as below:

Option 1 is buck converter output to coils and via a common mode choke to rest of circuitry.

[image]

Option 2 is to add ferrite bead on each controller's VCC line. But that would break down the main VCC plane into several small planes which wouldn't be ideal.

[image]

What do you guys think?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it got answered with a one line answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved on with power architecture 2.

Comment: Please explain why this is the right answer and expand your answer